# Problem in sending a message from content script to popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, messaging, content-script

In the chrome extension, I created a button on the website with the help of content script, when this button is clicked I want to take some information from the website and display it on the popup page but I am not succeeding in doing so.

To do this I send the information that I want to display on the extension as a message from content script to popup, but it fails to do it and returns an error **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist**. I found out that if the popup page is closed(inactive) it cannot receive any messages. But when I click the button on the website the popup page is always closed. Is there any solution to this problem? Here is the code I have written to send a message.

## content.js

```
// Create a button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Send Message";

// Add an event listener to the button
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Send a message to the popup page
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "Hello from the content script!"});
});

// Append the button to the body of the page
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

## popup.js

```
// Listen for messages from the content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Check the message
    if (request.message === "Hello from the content script!") {
      console.log("Received message: " + request.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: There are two problems with your extension.
chrome.runtime.sendMessage sends to background. Clicking the content script button closes the popup.

Comment: Instead of using `default_popup`, use chrome.action.onClicked in the background script and add the UI as an element to the web page e.g. an in iframe that points to your html exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).